# Ruby On Rails on Windows with Mongrel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby, mongrel

Where is the best tutorial for getting Ruby On Rails working on a windows box with Mongrel?  I'm a complete novice at server management, so the more detailed the better!

Answer (score 4):

You can follow this tutorial, it will get you setup you can actually manage your Mongrel server as a Windows service (start/stop/restart, start on boot, manage programatically etc etc):

[How to setup mongrel as a native Windows service](http://noobonrails.blogspot.com/2006/06/how-to-setup-mongrel-as-native-windows.html)

I'm currently using this method to manage an instance of Redmine on a Windows box and it works wonderfully.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the book "[Deploying Rails Applications](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/fr_deploy/deploying-rails-applications)" very useful. Specially the chapter "Deploying on Windows". It gives you step by step instructions to deploy a Rails application using Apache and Mongrel

Answer (score 0):

[Rubystack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) is a free Windows Rails installer that we keep up to date and includes Mongrel support out of the box